# Scala advanced features noMethodException when being called from java (Minecraft)

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using Scala version 2.12.4 and sbt version 1.0.4.

I am writing a plugin for minecraft using the sponge API in Scala, but every time I launch the plugin, I always get the:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
        at permissions.Permission.<init>(Permissions.scala:3) ~[Permission.class:0.1]
        at permissions.Permissions$.<init>(Permissions.scala:6) ~[Permissions$.class:0.1]
        at permissions.Permissions$.<clinit>(Permissions.scala) ~[Permissions$.class:0.1]
```

where each permission is a case class:

```
case class Permission(node: String)

object Permissions {
  val examplePerm: Permission = Permission("pixelmcutils.permission.enable")
```

> PS: A similar error appears when trying to use a simple for loop, or any implicit classes.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**Edit:** Solved by including the scala standard library the jar.

Comment: when you deploy, are you including the Scala library jars?

Comment: I used sbt assembly, but have justed added the scala libs to the fat jar and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement apply method in the companion object (object Permissions) if you want to create objects without new keyword

```
object Permissions {
  val examplePerm: Permission = Permission("pixelmcutils.permission.enable")
  def apply(node: String): Permission = {
     new Permissions(node)
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't apply only apply to classes and case classes?

Comment: Apply is special method for companion to not use new keyword. Probably you can add this method to the class either.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix the issue :(